# How to rebase a branch that's been branched off at different points

Tags: git, github

I have a branch called release which is branched from master a while back. Now today, I have two branches where one is based off of master called basedMaster and another branch that's based off of release called basedRelease. I recently made changes to master around 10+ commits. I know that you can `cherry-pick` those commmits but I want to figure out a way on how to rebase those 10+ commits onto the basedRelease branch. I'm assuming that those commits from basedMaster only 10+ are exactly what I want. I tried `rebasing` but it would grab the commits from other developers as well which is not what I wanted. So then I sourced another branch from basedMaster called basedMasterLocal thinking it would only carry the 10 commits I made to this branch basedRelease. However, I have been having trouble as to figure out how to do this as I don't want to use `cherry-pick` and would like to solve this using `rebase`

Comment: When you say you want to "*rebase those 10+ commits onto the basedRelease branch*", do you want to *copy* the commits or *move* them?

Comment: copy them over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's draw this out.

> I have a branch called release which is branched from master a while back.

```
A - B - C - F - G [master]
         \
          D - E [release]
```

> Now today, I have two branches where one is based off of master called basedMaster and another branch that's based off of release called basedRelease.

I assume you've added some commits on those branches, otherwise they're irrelevant.

```
                  H - I [basedMaster]
                 /
A - B - C - F - G [master]
         \
          D - E [release]
               \
                J - K [basedRelease]
```

> I recently made changes to master around 10+ commits.

Let's make that two.

```
                  H - I [basedMaster]
                 /
A - B - C - F - G - L - M [master]
         \
          D - E [release]
               \
                J - K [basedRelease]
```

> So then I sourced another branch from basedMaster called basedMasterLocal

```
                        [basedMasterLocal]
                  H - I [basedMaster]
                 /
A - B - C - F - G - L - M [master]
         \
          D - E [release]
               \
                J - K [basedRelease]
```

With this we have a better idea of the state of the repository.

> I want to figure out a way on how to rebase those 10+ commits onto the basedRelease branch.

It's unclear if you want all the commits which are in master but not in `basedRelease`, or just specifically those 10+ commits you mentioned. And it's unclear if you want to *copy* them (`cherry-pick`) or *move* them (`rebase`).

> I have been having trouble as to figure out how to do this as I don't want to use cherry-pick and would like to solve this using rebase.

Either way, you can cherry-pick multiple commits. It will take a range of commits. We can use `..` where `x..y` means "all the commits which are reachable from y excluding those reachable from x". See [gitrevisions/Specifying Ranges](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#_specifying_ranges) for more.

Assuming you have `basedRelease` checked out... if you want to copy (cherry-pick) all the commits in `master` but not in `basedRelease`.

```
# All the commits reachable from master
# excluding those reachable from HEAD (the currently checked out commit).
git cherry-pick HEAD..master
```

If it's just those 10+ commits, you can spell out those 10 commits. In this example it's just two, L and M.

```
git cherry-pick L M
```

Or you can observe that these are commits which are in `master` but not in `basedMaster`.

```
git cherry-pick basedMaster..master
```

And if you want to move (rebase) them.

```
git rebase --onto basedRelease basedMaster..master
```

There are similar examples in the [git-cherry-pick examples](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick#_examples) and [git-rebase has an similar example in its description](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#_description).

---

This sort of complex swapping commits between long-lived branches is one of the reasons why I recommend against having multiple long lived branches, and definitely against having branches off them. Keeping them in sync gets rapidly complicated.

Instead, I recommend having a single long lived branch: `master`. Nothing is committed directly to `master`. All work is done on short-lived feature branches. They must pass QA before being merged into `master`. Once merged they are deleted. This way `master` is always stable and ready for release. Releases are tracked with tags. This is the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow).

Comment: So I have these shortlived branches like basedMaster unless I'm mistakened. I understand how there could be a ranged cherrypick to specifically get my 10 commits but I figured if there were 10-15 commits to this one branch and I only want this then it would be better if I was able to get these commits and copy them over to the basedRelease branch. This is because in theory based release would want to contain the same commits as basedMasterLocal. I know that cherry-pick is a viable option but I figured rebase could copy my commits on basedMaster and move them over to basedRelease.

Comment: Unfortunately the release branch is long lived and I can't do much about it due to it being how our workspace is configured. If I understand correctly and assuming I'm on basedRelease I can use 
git rebase --onto basedRelease basedMaster..master which will get only those 10+ commits

Comment: @DavidZheng Rebase will *move* the commits. Cherry-pick will *copy* them. You said you want to copy the commits, so `git cherry-pick basedMaster..master`. Unless I misunderstood, basedRebase *will not* contain the same commits as basedMasterLocal. Use `git log --graph --decorate --all` to get a true picture of your repo, with the connections like in my drawings, but turned 90 degrees.